# Dynamically changing logo on scroll function

Tags: javascript, custom-header

I am migrating a static site over to WP. Currently I have a header function that changes the inverted logo to full color on user scroll using JS.
[See Function on scroll](https://synchronygroup.com/)

**Current JS for Scroll function:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    //Clears navbar timing functions on initial scroll
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    //Conditional to make function run if header is scroll pased 100px
    if ((top > 100) && $('#mainNav').is(':hidden')) {
        showNav();
        timeout = setTimeout(hideNav, 2000);
    } else if ((top > 100) && $('#mainNav').is(':visible')) {
        showNav();
        $('#logo').attr('src', './assets/sg-logo-inverted.svg');
        $('.nav-trigger-line').css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    } else {
        $('header').css({
            'background-color': 'transparent'
        });
        $('#logo').attr('src', './assets/sg-logo-inverted.svg');
        $('#logo').css({'width': '175px'});
        $('.nav-trigger-line').css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    }
});
```

**Current HTML Markup:**

```
<header class="fixed-top p-3">
    <!-- Logo and Burger -->
    <div class="container-fluid brand-wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="./assets/sg-logo-inverted.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Synchrony Group"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 trigger-wrapper py-1">
                <div id="burger">
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I have revised the mark in my header.php file to dynamically include the site logo via the WP Dashboard:

**Revised HTML Markup:**

```
<header class="fixed-top p-3">
    <!-- Logo and Burger -->
    <div class="container-fluid brand-wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img id="logo" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Synchrony Group">
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="col-6 trigger-wrapper py-1">
                <div id="burger">
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                    <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The Scroll Function still works but fails to replace the image because it looks for the image in the specific dir of the page, which does not exist.

**Question:** How can I dynamically change the logo on scroll function? Is this something that is handled by PHP rather than JS. What is the correct method to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the file you're trying to display is located in your theme folder.

You can use `get_template_directory_uri` to get the path of your currently activated theme's root folder.

If you're looking to support child themes `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will look in the currently activated child theme's folder if a child theme is in use.

If you must have your JavaScript in a seperate file, you should look into how to pass PHP variables to your JavaScript file with `wp_localize_script()`. This is pretty straight forward.

I usually pass a variable called `themeUrl` containing the URL of the theme folder and `baseUrl` containing the base URL of my site to my JavaScript.

Comment: I utilized `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and created an imgs folder in my theme dir.

Answer (score 0):

Without rewriting, you could just reference the absolute url.

So `...src', './wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_HERE/assets/sg-logo-inverted.svg'`

Or, a nicer way would be to use `wp_localize_script()` to reference the theme folder, and then you can access this via JavaScript.